# USB connection problem with Galaxy Ace

Tags: usb-connection-mode, samsung-galaxy-ace

My Galaxy Ace doesn't get recognized by my HP laptop with USB connection. When I tried to connect it with my friend's cable on his Dell laptop, it notified `CONNECTION UNSUCCESSFUL - NO DRIVER FOUND`. My phone still gets charged though. When I tried the `*#7284#` solution it wrote:

```
DIAG CONFIG
[1]USB[*]
[2]UART[]
[3]DBG MSG ON[]
[4]DBG MSG OFF[*]
```

I selected `[1]USB[*]` and it gave me:

```
USB_Diag Selected
Change Complete.
IF you change Uart or USB diag
Please reboot the mobile.
```

I'm not able to find MODEM->PDA mode.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the correct version of kies from samsung website and after successful installation check for kies update.

also try toggling under

settings->development->USB debugging, w/wo connecting USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the cable. Once I tried a normal USB cable for a Samsung Nexus S phone, and the connection failed. The cable that was given together with the phone worked. The official cable's shape is a little bit different from a normal cable. It has a small cylindrical protrusion on the wire.

I know this sounds strange, but it might matter.